# Calculations over Multiple Rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have data in the format;

```
Account  | Period     | Values
Revenue  | 2013-01-01 | 5432
Revenue  | 2013-02-01 | 6471
Revenue  | 2013-03-01 | 7231
Costs    | 2013-01-01 | 4321
Costs    | 2013-02-01 | 5672
Costs    | 2013-03-01 | 4562
```

And I want to get results out like;

```
Account  | Period     | Values
Margin   | 2013-01-01 | 1111
Margin   | 2013-02-01 |  799
Margin   | 2013-03-01 | 2669
M%       | 2013-01-01 |  .20
M%       | 2013-02-01 |  .13
M%       | 2013-03-01 |  .37
```

Where Margin = Revenue - Costs and M% is (Revenue - Costs)/Revenue for each period.

I can see various ways of achieving this but all are quite ugly and I wanted to know if there was elegant general approach for these sorts of multi-row calculations.

Thanks

**Edit**

Some of these calculations can get really complicated like

Free Cash Flow = Margin - Opex - Capex + Change in Working Capital + Interest Paid

So I am hoping for a general method that doesn't require lots of joins back to itself.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server Version = 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, then just Max over a Case statement, like such:

```
with RevAndCost as (revenue,costs,period)
as
(

    select "Revenue" = Max(Case when account="Revenue" then Values else null end),
           "Costs" = MAX(Case when account="Costs" then values else null end),
           period
            from data
    group by period

)

select Margin = revenue-costs,
       "M%" = (revenue-costs)/nullif(revenue,0)
from RevAndCost
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a full self-join with a Union

```
Select 'Margin' Account, 
   coalesce(r.period, c.period) Period,
   r.Values - c.Values Values
From myTable r
   Full Join Mytable c
      On c.period = r.period
Union
Select 'M%' Account, 
   coalesce(r.period, c.period) Period,
   (r.Values - c.Values) / r.Values Values
From myTable r
   Full Join Mytable c
      On c.period = r.period
```

Comment: It definitely works but would I have to add another FULL JOIN every time I wanted to include another row in my column. EG. (using rows I haven't shown something I need to calculate is; Free Cash Flow = Margin - Opex - Capex + Change in Working Capital + Interest Paid. Which would need 5 Full Joins If i understand your query rightly.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a Common Table Expression to do a full outer join between two instances of your data table to pull in Revenue and Costs into 1 table, then select from that CTE.

```
with RevAndCost as (revenue,costs,period)
as
(
    select  ISNULL(rev.Values,0) as revenue, 
            ISNULL(cost.values,0) as costs, 
        ISNULL(rev.period,cost.period)
    from data rev full outer join data cost
    on rev.period=cost.period
)

select Margin = revenue-costs,
   "M%" = (revenue-costs)/nullif(revenue,0)
from RevAndCost
```

Comment: Again I like this but is there a way that wouldn't require another FULL JOIN for every row I wanted to include.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT r.PERIOD, r.VALUES AS revenue, c.VALUES AS cost,
r.VALUES - c.VALUES AS margin, (r.VALUES - c.VALUES) / r.VALUES AS mPct
FROM 
    (SELECT PERIOD, VALUES FROM t WHERE
    ACCOUNT = 'revenue') r INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PERIOD, VALUES FROM t WHERE
    ACCOUNT = 'costs') c ON
    r.PERIOD = c.PERIOD
```