# Redshift SQL: Inter row calculations based on another column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am building a table in Redshift as a basis for a [Bowling Chart](http://www.velaction.com/bowling-chart/).

I got my data to this format:

`data`:

```
month   | product_id  | kpi_type  | values
april   |     1       | current   | 330
april   |     1       | target    | 300
april   |     2       | current   | 340
april   |     2       | target    | 300
march   |     2       | current   | 270
march   |     2       | target    | 300
```

I want to insert a `kpi_type = diff` where `diff = current-target`.

I am looking to get to this:

```
month   | product_id  | kpi_type  | values
april   |     1       | current   | 330
april   |     1       | target    | 300
april   |     1       | diff      | 30
april   |     2       | current   | 340
april   |     2       | target    | 300
april   |     2       | diff      | 40
march   |     2       | current   | 270
march   |     2       | target    | 300
march   |     2       | diff      | -30
```

I know how to get there by calculating the diff in CTEs and then unioning it to the original table. However I want to do this over a lot of different `values` and with more complex variance formulas so I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Here's where I got:

```
    select
        a.month,
        a.product_id,   
        a.values as current,
        b.target,
        a.values - b.target as diff
    from data a
    left join
        (
            select
            month,
            product_id,
            values as target
            from data
            where kpi_type = 'target'
        ) b
    on md5(a.month || a.product_id) = md5(b.month || b.product_id)
    where kpi_type = 'current'
    group by 1,2,3
```

From there I could union it back to `data` and get the desired result, but it does not seem efficient.

[Close to this question on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652858/calculations-over-multiple-rows-sql-server).

Comment: If you're looking for an "efficient" solution, then you should be storing one line per month+product combination and storing current and target as columns (rather than as separate rows). This will make your reporting much simpler. You could transform (ETL) your existing table into another table of this format and use the new table for queries.

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately I need to have the `kpi_types` as rows for vizualisation purposes when I pull into my bi tool - I'm looking to get the same format as the link referenced in the question, and my bi tool is column based.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be one value per month,product_id for kpi_types current and target, you can aggregate to get the diff row and use `union all` to combine it with the original result.

```
select month,product_id,kpi_type,values from data
union all
select month,product_id,'diff' as kpi_type,   
coalesce(max(case when kpi_type='current' then values end),0) - 
coalesce(max(case when kpi_type='target' then values end),0) as values
from data 
group by month,product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not use the comment function. So I will write it here. I think there is no other way than using union to transpose data in redshift. So you might use window function for the subtraction instead of left join query to get diff.

```
 sum(values)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY month, product_id ) AS diff
```

First you might do something like that in a sub query:

```
    SELECT
       CASE WHEN type = 'target'
         THEN values * -1
       ELSE values END AS values
     FROM data
```

Then you can union it.